# What is the measurement of the top of the trapezoid that will give the greatest area?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I tried solving this homework but with no success. I got stuck.

[image]

I tried drawing the trough and this is I got:

[image]

I only know that the surface area of the trapezoidal prism is $h(a+30)+58(a+2b+30)$

I got stuck from here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that the problem seems to be asking you to find the area of the cross section, not the surface area of the prism.

Comment: Can you find a formula for the height of the trapezoid in terms of $a$ and $b$? Hint: make two right triangles.

Comment: @AnnieCarter I thought of that as well, but I also thought that it's a trough, and our lessons is on solids. I will try to do that with the height.

Comment: @AnnieCarter I am so sorry but I still don't understand how I should use the height. I tried creating two right triangles and that gave me $(\frac{a}{2})^2 + h^2$ = hypotenuse.

Comment: There's an ambiguity here—I'm interpreting the 58 cm as being the total width of the strip before it's bent, which allows you to solve for the hypotenuse of the triangles, but you're interpreting it as the total length of the trough. Note that the base of the triangle isn't $a/2$, because you have to remove a rectangular piece (how wide?) from the trapezoid to form the two right triangles.